# MemSQL - How to fix union with a child in subquery

Tags: database, singlestore

When I executed the following query in Memsql, I got the following message:

"Feature 'union with a child select that is not sharded inside a pushed down query' is not supported by MemSQL Distributed."

```
SELECT *
              FROM customer_campaigns t45 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                                                             t164.source_entity_id      AS source_entity_id,
                                                             t164.destination_entity_id AS destination_entity_id,
                                                             t164.status                AS STATUS
                                                           FROM campaign_mirror_references t164 INNER JOIN
                                                             mirror_configurations t160
                                                               ON ((t164.mirror_config_id = t160.id) AND
                                                                   (t160.is_sync = 1))
                                                             INNER JOIN customer_campaigns t45
                                                               ON (t45.campaign_id = t160.source_campaign_id)
                                                           WHERE (t45.cust_profile_id = 416)
                                                           UNION DISTINCT SELECT
                                                                            t164.source_entity_id      AS source_entity_id,
                                                                            t164.destination_entity_id AS destination_entity_id,
                                                                            t164.status                AS STATUS
                                                                          FROM
                                                                            campaign_mirror_references t164 INNER JOIN
                                                                            mirror_configurations t160 ON (
                                                                            (t164.mirror_config_id = t160.id) AND
                                                                            (t160.is_sync = 1) AND
                                                                            (t160.dest_profile_id = 416))) AS SOURCE
                  ON ((t45.campaign_id = SOURCE.source_entity_id) AND (SOURCE.status <> 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a requirement that this be written as a single query? For readability and to simplify the nesting, could you try making a temporary table and then selecting from that? This should get the same effect as what you have above, but is a little easier to follow:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpCampaignMirrorRefs;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpCampaignMirrorRefs AS
SELECT t164.source_entity_id AS source_entity_id
    , t164.destination_entity_id AS destination_entity_id
    , t164.status AS STATUS
FROM campaign_mirror_references t164
INNER JOIN mirror_configurations t160 ON t164.mirror_config_id = t160.id
    AND t160.is_sync = 1
WHERE t45.cust_profile_id = 416
UNION
SELECT t164.source_entity_id AS source_entity_id
    , t164.destination_entity_id AS destination_entity_id
    , t164.status AS STATUS
FROM campaign_mirror_references t164
INNER JOIN mirror_configurations t160 ON t164.mirror_config_id = t160.id
    AND t160.is_sync = 1
    AND t160.dest_profile_id = 416
;

SELECT *
FROM customer_campaigns t45
LEFT OUTER JOIN tmpCampaignMirrorRefs SOURCE ON t45.campaign_id = SOURCE.source_entity_id
    AND SOURCE.status <> 2
;
```

Let me know if there are any other problems--hope this helps!

Also FWIW, `UNION` == `UNION DISTINCT` in MemSQL :)

Comment: In our Memsql version, single query work faster than two separated queries.
So I prefer it in single query.
But thanks for the try :)